# Is there a term for localizations of commutative affine algebras?

Tags: commutative-algebra, terminology

In commutative algebra, is there some known terminology that can help me shorten the phrase "is some localization of an affine commutative $k$-algebra"? Alternatively, is there some equivalent condition that already has nice terminology?

Comment: "Essentially of finite type over $k$" might be the term you are looking for.

Comment: That's precisely what I wanted, thanks! If you make your comment an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Here are some references. \[Stacks, [Tag 07DR](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07DR)\] has the basic definitions but omits some proofs. These proofs can be found in \[[EGAIV$_1$](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1964__20__5_0), (1.3.8)ff\], which may be where this notion was first defined. For the corresponding scheme-theoretic notion, see \[[Nayak 2009](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2009.05.002), Def. 2.1ff\].